# Why am I getting this UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning error when running npm build on my serverless project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, es6-modules

I am getting the following error when trying to run npm build on my serverless aws-nodejs-typescript project and do not understand how to fix it. Anyone able to point me in the right direction please?

```
npm build 
(node:44390) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/chalk/source/index.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/chalk/source/index.js from /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/explain-dep.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/chalk/package.json.
...
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: You probably need to update your node packages. You need to be using Chalk 5.0.0 if you are using modules.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of chalk has changed to ES6 import/export syntax instead of CJS (CommonJS with `require`). So instead of:

```js
const chalk = require('chalk');
```

You have to do:

```js
import chalk from 'chalk';
```

You'll (unfortunately) have to change all the other requires into imports as well, then change all your `module.exports` into `export default` and all your `exports.whatever` to `export whatever;` where whatever is your thing, or as suggested rename your file to `index.cjs` to force CJS.

Then there are the docs for [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) if you need them.

Then, you need to add `type: "module"` to package.json. So much for chalk :)

<sup>I didn't like that so I used to just use colors intead, but...</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - let me try this and update here afterward! Thanks very much!!

Comment: What do I do about 3rd party libraries that I am using? And what if they haven't updated to use export default yet?

Comment: @Nik you can use import/export for them too.